# Snow Leopard doesn't repair permissions, despite showing / saying its fixed them?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, permissions, disk-utility

Sometime ago, I used carbon copy as I was replacing my hard drive in my Mac Mini running Snow Leopard. Afterwards, on my new drive I had some permission problems.

I've tried several times running a repair permissions / repair disk from disk util. It shows that there are problems and I think it says its correceted the problems.

However the problems remain, what can I do to fix them ?

It doesn't seem to cause me any problems, that I can tell

EDIT

```
Repairing permissions for “Macintosh HD”
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jconsole.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jconsole.jar".
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib", should be 95, user is 0.
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib".
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries", should be 95, user is 0.
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreenLeopard386.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreenLeopard386.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Dutch.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Italian.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/French.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/German.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/Japanese.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/RemoteDesktopMenu.nib".
Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired.
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/UIAgent.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Support/Remote Desktop Message.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/UIAgent.nib".
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/Support/LockScreen.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib".
Group differs on "private/var/log/kernel.log", should be 80, group is 0.
Permissions differ on "private/var/log/kernel.log", should be -rw-r----- , they are -rw-r--r-- .
Repaired "private/var/log/kernel.log".
Group differs on "private/var/log/secure.log", should be 80, group is 0.
Permissions differ on "private/var/log/secure.log", should be -rw-r----- , they are -rw-r--r-- .
Repaired "private/var/log/secure.log".
Group differs on "private/var/log/system.log", should be 80, group is 0.
Permissions differ on "private/var/log/system.log", should be -rw-r----- , they are -rw-r--r-- .
Repaired "private/var/log/system.log".

Permissions repair complete
```

Comment: How do your permission problems manifest?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: What I meant was, if you experience any *real* issues? These permission things aren't really that important.

Comment: No I haven't so far and I've had them a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Repairing permissions will leave some permissions unchanged. If your MAC works without issues don't worry about it.

Comment: Additional info from Apple Support: [Mac OS X: Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions messages that you can safely ignore](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1448)

Comment: I almost want to give my first downvote for this answer. Why? Because this is not "normal", even if it is a common problem. It is a bug, and by definition, a bug is not normal, acceptable functionality. Sure, most of the time for most people, it's nothing to worry about. But this advice is almost worthless without joelseph's additional info that clarifies exactly when one should not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I'm getting the exact same list of permissions, not being repaired!  My guess is some bad coding in java that will be fixed in a future release